# How to search a range of cells for specific txt, then copy to adjacent cell

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, vba

I have a range of cells, e.g. g1-g1000 that contains two type of entries: xx.xx  or xx.xxCR, where xx.xx are numbers.

I want to search the range of cells for xx.xxCR and when a cell is found, copy the contents to the adjacent cell minus the CR, then delete the value in the original cell.

Cells that contain xx.xx will not haven any thing done to them.

E.G.  cell g5 contains 23.67CR; after running the algorighm, cell h5 contains 23.67 and g5 is empty.

Do this for the range of values in g0-g1000

Here is my attempt:

```
Dim i
 For i = 1 To 30  
 If InStr(UCase(Cells(i, "G")), "CR") Then  
 MsgBox "The string 'CR' was found in cell " & Cells(i, "G").Address(0, 0)  
 ' Copy the cell containing xx.xxCR to the adjacent cell  
 Range(Cells(i, "G")).Select  
 Range(Cells(i, "G")).Copy  
 Range(Cells(i, "H")).Select  
 ActiveSheet.Paste  
 ' Remove the CR from the adjacent cell e.g. "C", just leaving xx.xx  
 Cells(i, "H") = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(Cells(i, "H"), "CR", "")  
 'Remove the contents of the cell where CR was found  
 '?? what should go here?  
 End If  
 Next
```

I keep getting runtime error `1004 Application defined or object defined error at the line:Range(Cells(i, "G")).Select`

Can someone spot the error of my ways?

Comment: I believe your problem is the "G".  Cells(x,y) wants integers for both; try using 7 for "G", and 8 for "H".

Answer (score 0):

I see several errors in your ways, for instance it is considered bad practice both to not specify where your cells and ranges are located more explicitly than you do and to use `.select`. Some of the `Select`-statements are also superfluous, you do not need to select the cell when you qualify it with a range-reference in your code. And while I'll applaud you for actually declaring your variables, you should also say what you declare them as. In this instance, either `Dim i as Long` or `Dim i as Integer` ([the first one is slightly better for complicated reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26409117/why-use-integer-instead-of-long)).

The syntax you use for specifying ranges is also invalid, as DarkMoon mentions, and although you could have achieved something like what you want doing e.g. `Range("G"&CStr(i))` I would really urge you to include at least what spreadsheet you are on first. I.e. `Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("G"&CStr(i))`

Here is how I would solve what  you're trying to  do, with a few comments on what the different bits of code do. You'll note that I didn't include the messagebox which is in your code, in case you get a lot of hits over the 1000 rows, I bet you don't want to click that OK-button more than a few 100 times ;)

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()
  Dim range_to_search As Range, string_to_find  As String, found_cell As Range, first_address As String

  ' Turn off a couple  of settings to make the code run faster
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Application.EnableEvents = False
  Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

  ' Set the value to search for, and the range to search in
  string_to_find = "CR"
  Set range_to_search = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("G1:G1000")

  ' Find the first cell in the range containing the searchstring
  Set found_cell = range_to_search.Find(What:=string_to_find, After:=range_to_search(range_to_search.CountLarge, 1), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False)
  ' No point in doing anything if no cell containing the string is found
  If Not found_cell Is Nothing Then
    ' This isn't strictly necessary since we clear the cells as we go along, but at the end of the macro, we'll use this string to make sure we don't loop over the range again  and again
    first_address = found_cell.Address
    ' Start of loop
    Do
      ' Replace the string we're searching for with a zero-length string
      found_cell = Replace(found_cell, string_to_find, "", 1, -1, vbTextCompare)
      ' Copy the edited value to the adjacent column
      found_cell.Copy Destination:=found_cell.Offset(0, 1)
      ' Clear the cell
      found_cell.ClearContents
      ' Find a possible next value
      Set found_cell = range_to_search.FindNext(found_cell)
      ' If we haven't found a new cell containing the searchstring, we exit the loop
      If found_cell Is Nothing Then Exit Do
    ' Have we reached the top again? If not, keep looping.
    Loop While found_cell.Address <> first_address
  End If

  ' Turn the settings back on
  Application.EnableEvents = True
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
  Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```